# nodejs exec sync print out live updates

Tags: node.js, terminal

I currently have an javascript file that looks like the below.

index.js:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const push = execSync('git push', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
console.log(push);
```

execSync waits until the command finishes before printing out the result. How can I make it so that it can print out live updates?

Comment: use spawn instead, https://nodejs.org/docs/v8.1.4/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't want to change my code too much, I have multiple files that do this but execute different commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the `stdio` option as `inherit` via https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const push = execSync('git push', {
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  stdio: 'inherit',
});
```